# Função hash em java

Tags: java, hash

Alguém poderia me mostrar (e explicar) uma função hash(função de dispersão) sem ser a de divisao? (key % tamanho)? Gostaria que fosse uma simples (e que exista). No caso tenho uma tabela de 11 posições que deve calclar a partir do numero do cpf seu indice, mas sem usar cpf % tamanho_tabela.

Comment: Qual sua dúvida exata? Posso sugerir o `Integer.hashCode()`, que é basicamente `return this;` como exemplo de hash fácil?

Comment: Tenho uma tabela de 11 posições, vou receber um cpf com 11 algarismos e usando uma função de dispersão devo coloca-lo na tabela. Mas sem usar a função cpf % tamanho_tabela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia interpretar os 11 dígitos como um `BigInteger`, multiplicar por um número primo bem grande (idealmente, maior que um número de CPF, ou seja 12 dígitos), como por exemplo 112287187009. Assim:

```
private static final BigInteger PRIME = new BigInteger("112287187009");
private static final BigInteger ONZE = BigInteger.valueOf(11);

public int hashCpf(String cpf) {
    BigInteger v = new BigInteger(cpf.replace(".", "").replace("-", ""));
    return BigInteger.multiply(PRIME).remainder(11).intValue();
}
```